# CVIVI CRM setup on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cron-job, setup

Please can an expert assist me in setting up Civi CRM on wordpress.
Cronjobs and mail
I have done basic configurations, but not sure about cron jobs.
Need also to add in new forms, and how to add them.
Need someone with full setup from start to finish please

Comment: Agree with Aidan - unclear what 'need someone with full set up from start to finish pls' really means. this is a voluntary support system. paid support is available via other means

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE!

If you want to pay someone to do it for you then see https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

If you want free community help to do it yourself then you'll need to describe in more detail what you have already done and the problems you have encountered.  Have you read the documentation on cron jobs and checked the other cron questions here? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/